# What is ohm joules (ΩJ) unit used for?

Tags: resistors, components, markings

I found the following component but I don't know what it is. In particular, what does the **ΩJ** unit mean?

[image: photo of component marked 5W 10mΩJ]

Comment: the J is likely a separate symbol, probably referring to tolerance.

Answer (score 21):

That's not J for joules. It's probably [J for 5% tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKM_code#Tolerance_code). The component is just a 10 mΩ resistor with a 5 W rating.

Comment: Probably we have a dupe somewhere on the site for this kind of code, but I wasn't able to turn it up with a bit of searching.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/484095/47070

Answer (score 18):

"J" means a resistor value tolerance of +/- 5% as per [this site](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/resistors-value-letter-digit-code-d_1656.html).

The resistor in question has a value of 10 milli-ohms (\$m\Omega\$).

It also applies to capacitors as per [this wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKM_code): -

[image]